# Some Windows key shortcuts not working

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11

**Windows 11 22622.601**

I have identified that the following <kbd>Win</kbd> key shortcuts are not working. If a shortcut is not listed here, that means it is working. Note, this is not an issue with the physical keyboard; these shortcuts do not work using the on-screen keyboard, either.

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

It has been this way on my machine on the beta Insider channel for the last few updates, and what seemed to be the trigger was either logging out or switching accounts. Normally, just rebooting and logging into the same account I rebooted from would resolve the issue, but that is no longer working. This is now the constant behavior. I have tried to anticipate some potential questions and answered them below:

- No Auto Hotkey
- Not a gaming keyboard with the <kbd>Win</kbd> key disabled (remember, only the above combos don't work; <kbd>Win</kbd> and other combos still work)
- No other macro software except Logitech Options, but this would not affect the On-Screen Keyboard
- Task View still works using the Taskbar button, and I can switch desktops from there
- I checked for funny-looking tasks in Task Scheduler that trigger on logout; found none
- HID keyboard shortcut service is running
- `sfc /scannow` does not fix it; a pox on the next lazy Windows support rep that suggests that to a hapless rube looking for help
- Group or Local Policy is not disabling <kbd>Win</kbd>
- It happened about a month ago after an Insider update (I'm on the beta channel), I think right before the 21/22 split
- I didn't have time to roll back, and I convinced myself I could fix it and live with the reboots in the meantime
- Reboots are currently not working anymore, hence this post
- I could not find any other posts that match my exact situation, and I tried fixes from similar posts to no avail
- I know this is an Insider build; I've already filed feedback in Feedback Hub
- Yes, I regret not rolling back when I could
- Yes, I can reinstall Windows; I'd rather gnaw off my arm, though
- Yes, it is my fault for being on an Insider build

Please halp :(

Comment: This seems to be a Windows bug, so the chances are slim that we can fix it without access to Microsoft sources. However, does this happen when booting in Safe mode? Can you find an ISO for the Insider channel that dates from before the change so you can downgrade (but this will block you for some time in this version)?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I put it in Safe Mode and the bad behavior persisted. I'll probably just proceed with a reinstall rather than rollback if I don't find another way to resolve the issue.

Comment: I may have found the source of the problem. I believe it's an odd interaction between the startup of the apps Synergy and LogiOptions+. I've added some delays to the timing of the Synergy service using Services and Task Scheduler. I'm testing it out for the next few days, and if it works consistently, I'll add the answer in case any other person runs into this weird situation.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Windows 11 Insider Preview. This means that you have
nominated yourself as a tester for Windows 11 versions that may still/surely
contain bugs.

Unless you are a developer and wish to ensure that your program will
still work in this future version, you shouldn't stay in the
Insider program.

Here is how to leave the Insider program:

- Open *Settings > Update & Security > Windows Insider Program*
- Turn on "Stop getting preview builds"
- Click the Restart now button (if applicable).